# Setting char* field in struct, C language

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct body{
    char* text;
} body_t;
```

I want to write a function that allows me to set and get the text of a body struct to a string that I pass it. I wrote the following functions:

```
void body_set_text(body_t* body, char* text){
    if(body->text != NULL){
        free(body->text);
    }
    body->text = text;
}

char* body_get_text(body_t* body){
    return body->text;
}
```

The text field in a body can be multiple characters or a single character. I want to use the body_set_text function to modify the text given some user input that is a single character. I wrote the following function:

```
void process_player_entry(body_t* body, char c){
    char* new_char = malloc(sizeof(char));
    snprintf(new_char, "%c", c);
    body_set_text(body, new_char);
}
```

However, this throws me a heap buffer overflow error. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The 2nd argument to snprintf should be a size.

Comment: To hold a string of length N, you must allocate a buffer of at least N+1.  A buffer of size 1 cannot hold a string except the trivial string with length 0.

Comment: `free(NULL)` is perfectly safe.  There is no real point in checking if the pointer is non-NULL before calling `free`.

Comment: Note that if you call `body_set_text(something, "hello")`, then the next call to `body_set_text(something, ...)` will fail miserably because you can't `free("hello")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several other problems in your code, as pointed out by other people in the comments. However, you can make it work by giving [`snprintf(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) the correct arguments:

```
// function signature
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);

// the second argument is "size"

void process_player_entry(body_t* body, char c){
    // change here to "2", so you have space for the character and
    // the NULL terminator
    char* new_char = malloc(2);
    // so changing here should be fine
    snprintf(new_char, 1, "%c", c);
    body_set_text(body, new_char);
}
```

From the manual:

> The functions **snprintf()** and **vsnprintf()** *write at most size bytes* (**including the terminating null byte ('\0')**) to str.